# Install Python 2.7.* in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows

I am using Windows 10. Just now, have installed Python 3.5 64 bit successfully. However, when I want to install Python 2.7.*, the following error is shown.

[image]

I even uninstalled Python 3.5, but no luck. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you download once again and try installing?

Comment: Which file do you attempt to install?

Comment: @be_good_do_good I have tried 2.7.12 and 2.7.9, neither is okay.

Comment: @cdarke you mean directory? E:\Python27

Comment: did you do a fresh download and try?

Comment: @StevenLuo , can you please download https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.12/python-2.7.12.amd64.msi and install

Comment: No I meant which file did you download to install.

Comment: @cdarke I downloaded Python 2.7 Windows x86-64 MSI installer.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I solved the problem by installing a 32-bit version.